# when using XML parse, is the xml resource the object you access?

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I dont seem to quite understand how xml_parse works.  What i was doing was getting the contents of the xml file, create a parser, and pass it into xml_parse().  I dont know what to do after that.  I was thinking that in my case, $xml was the array i can now iterate through.  I was trying to see how i would parse my data.

```
    $fp = file_get_contents("memberdata.xml");
echo "pre-create";
$xml = xml_parser_create();
echo "pre-parse";
$status = xml_parse($xml,$fp);

if(!$status){
    die("Error parsing data from $fp into $xml");
}
echo "pre XML posting";
echo "<br />".$xml."<br />";
print_r($xml);
xml_parser_free($xml);
```

I cant seem to figure out how to access this.

Sample xml data is as follows:

```
<currentTime>2012-09-05 03:43:25</currentTime>
<result>
  <rowset name="members" key="characterID" columns="characterID,name,startDateTime,baseID,base,title,logonDateTime,logoffDateTime,locationID,location,shipTypeID,shipType,roles,grantableRoles">
    <row ..>
  </rowset>
</result>
<cachedUntil></cashedUntil>
```

Comment: Not worthy of an answer, but I would suggest using either `SimpleXML` or `DOMDocument` (both built in to PHP).  You will get a lot more support for those.  I've never heard of `xml_parser` before this question!

Comment: i saw those on php.net, but i thought those were things i needed to install, and i was thinking to just do it the with basic stuff.  Let me take a look at SimpleXML then.

Comment: They are libraries for PHP but with a vanilla PHP install they should be included.  They will only be excluded if you do a PHP install that excludes them specifically.

Comment: I just tried SimpleXML. Sweet baby jesus it is now really easy.  lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the base tools, using one of the toolkits, SimpleXML will alleviate a lot of the frustrations.  The answer to this question is redone using SimpleXML.

```
    $fp = file_get_contents("memberdata.xml");
$eve = new SimpleXMLElement($fp);

$cols = $eve->{'result'}->rowset['columns'];
//I put result in {} because result is a special character in php.
$cols = explode(",",$cols);
foreach ($cols as $c){
    echo "".$c."<br />";
}
    //output is printed to screen
```

---